# Limitar o input

Tags: python

> Quando o usuário responde o input está printando o (Limite é 10, insira um valor até 10), sendo que e era para printar a matriz, eu so quero que printa o limite 10 quando o usuário digitar um número maior que 10 na linha ou coluna da matriz.

Qual o erro do meu código ?

```
import random

# Gera a matriz com os números aleatórios de 0 à 90.
def matriz_aleatoria(li, col):
    linha = []
    for lin in range(li):
        coluna = []
        for c in range(col):
            coluna.append(random.randint(0, 91))
        linha.append(coluna)
    return (linha)

# B = vetor B, Verifica quais são pares e impares e joga na ordem de pares e depois impares.
def par_e_impar(mat):
    B = []
    for linha in mat:
        for col in linha:
            if col % 2 == 0:
                B.insert(0, col)
            else:
                B.append(col)
    return (B)
# Verifica se informou somente número para saber a quantidade de linhas e colunas.
while True:
    col = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: '))
    lin = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: '))
    if col and lin:
        mat = matriz_aleatoria(int(lin),int(col))
        B = par_e_impar(mat)
        break
# Caso não tenha informado número, imprime a mensagem para inserir somente número.
    else:
        print('Por favor, insira somente a quantidade de colunas e linhas em número !!!')
# Limitar a quantidade que o usuário pode digitar.
while True:
    if col or lin >= 11:
        print('Limite é 10, insira um valor até 10.')
        break
    else:
        print(B)
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá, blz?
Para o loop infinito parar basta retirar o ultimo while. Caso vc queira continuar usando um While, utilize uma Flag para sair do loop. Esqueça isso de Break. Vale lembrar que ele só acusará o erro caso a linha AND coluna seja maior que 10. seria bom fazer uma crítica para cada um. linha or coluna.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim utilizando uma flag:

```
import random

# Gera a matriz com os números aleatórios de 0 à 90.
def matriz_aleatoria(li, col):
    linha = []
    for lin in range(li):
        coluna = []
        for c in range(col):
            coluna.append(random.randint(0, 91))
        linha.append(coluna)
    return (linha)

# B = vetor B, Verifica quais são pares e impares e joga na ordem de pares e depois impares.
def par_e_impar(mat):
    B = []
    for linha in mat:
        for col in linha:
            if col % 2 == 0:
                B.insert(0, col)
            else:
                B.append(col)
    return (B)
# Verifica se informou somente número para saber a quantidade de linhas e colunas.
temp = False
while not temp:
    col = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: '))
    lin = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: '))
    if col and lin:
        mat = matriz_aleatoria(int(lin),int(col))
        B = par_e_impar(mat)
    if col and lin >= 11:
        print('Limite é 10, insira um valor até 10.')
        col = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: '))
        lin = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: '))
    else:
        if col and lin <= 10:
            temp = True
            print(B)
# Caso não tenha informado número, imprime a mensagem para inserir somente número.
        else:
            print('Por favor, insira somente a quantidade de colunas e linhas em número !!!')
# Limitar a quantidade que o usuário pode digitar.
```

Comment: Blz Pedro, acabei trocando o "and" por "or" no if col or lin <=10:

Comment: Porém agora quando digito qqer valor ele está somente printando que o limite é 10 e não gera a matriz.

Comment: ele só irá gerar a matriz se o valor digitado for correto

Comment: Então eu estou digitando o valor correto, porém está printando que o limite é 10, até tentei inverter o if, se o valor for menor ou igual a 10 printa a matriz, se não printa que o limite é 10. Só que ao inverter ele não printa o limite e fica gerando a matriz com qqer valor que eu coloco

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. O unico problema é que agora se eu digitar um caracter ao invés de número ele da erro. Vou tentar criar uma validação para não aceitar caracter.

Comment: Não estou sabendo usar essa plataforma kkkkk
Entrei hoje pra ver como era, desculpe

Comment: Outra coisa, tire os 2 primeiros input's de dentro do while, senão irá ficar repetindo sem motivo. deixe logo acima do while, caso tenha digitado errado ele irá entrar na crítica e ser perguntado novamente

Comment: Eu sou novo também, obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu o maior problema.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Olá, resolvi o problema caso coloque letras : )

```
import random

# Gera a matriz com os números aleatórios de 0 à 90.
def matriz_aleatoria(li, col):
    linha = []
    for lin in range(li):
        coluna = []
        for c in range(col):
            coluna.append(random.randint(0, 91))
        linha.append(coluna)
    return (linha)

# B = vetor B, Verifica quais são pares e impares e joga na ordem de pares e depois impares.
def par_e_impar(mat):
    B = []
    for linha in mat:
        for col in linha:
            if col % 2 == 0:
                B.insert(0, col)
            else:
                B.append(col)
    return (B)
# Verifica se informou somente número para saber a quantidade de linhas e colunas.

temp = False
col = input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: ')
lin = input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: ')


while not temp:
    while not col.isnumeric() or not lin.isnumeric():
        print("Digite somente números")
        col = input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: ')
        lin = input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: ')
    else:
        col = int(col)
        lin = int(lin)
    if col and lin:
        mat = matriz_aleatoria(int(lin),int(col))
        B = par_e_impar(mat)
    if col > 10 or lin > 10:
        print('Limite é 10, insira um valor até 10.')
        col = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de colunas da matriz: '))
        lin = int(input('Coloque a quantidade de linhas da matriz: '))
    else:
        if col <= 10 and lin <= 10:
            temp = True
            print(B)
# Caso não tenha informado número, imprime a mensagem para inserir somente número.
        else:
            print('Por favor, insira somente a quantidade de colunas e linhas em número !!!')
# Limitar a quantidade que o usuário pode digitar.
```

Analise o que fiz e tentei deixar do seu jeito

Comment: Obrigado, mas quando eu digito o número da coluna maior doq o número de linhas, ele está dando erro e trava.

Comment: E da outra maneira ele está aceitando o número de colunas maior que 10 e número de linha menor que 10. Estou tentando resolver esse problema, porque quando eu digito número de linha maior que 10 e a coluna menor que 10  o programa avisa que o limite é 10.

Comment: Na parte da pessoa colocar o caracter eu utilizei try e except, no try fica o código e o except eu coloquei que é para digitar somente número. Deu certo

Comment: Não sei se entendeu, mas quando digito um valor da COLUNA maior que 10 e a linha menor que 10 ele aceita, e quando é o contrário ele não aceita e informa que o limite é 10.